# Custom button is not visible in Community view

Tags: community, custom-button, partner-communities

i have implemented small custom button on account object, that custom button will showing salesforce classic view, but its not visible in community view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Javascript buttons don't work in Lightning at all. You will need to find an alternative mechanism to run this logic - perhaps a Visualforce page you can send the user to with a button, or a quick action.

most of the logic of our business resides in those buttons that are not supported in Salesforce1 and lightning experience but are supported in Salesforce Classic